# How to make the input not affecting the background?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I have a login form and I want to lay an color gradient under the input fields. But somehow the background in the input is not behaving normally but somehow blurred and magnified. I tried to make ion-input `{ opacity: O%; }` but that didn't work.

Here is the code and a picture of the problem:
[image]

html

```
<ion-content padding>

<h2> Login </h2>

<form \[formGroup\]="loginForm"> 

   <ion-item class="input-item">
   <!--  <ion-label position="floating"> <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> Username or Email</ion-label> -->
     <ion-input 
     type="text" 
     placeholder="Username" 
     formControlName="username" 
     clearInput  
     inputmode="text"
      ></ion-input> 
   </ion-item>



   <ion-item class="input-item">
    <!-- <ion-label position="floating"> <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> Password</ion-label> -->
    <app-show-hide-password>
     <ion-input 
     type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"
      ></ion-input>  
   </app-show-hide-password>
    </ion-item>



   <ion-button 
      type="submit"
      expand="block"  
      shape="round" 
      color="primary" 
      \[disabled\]="!loginForm.valid"
    > Login </ion-button>

  </form>

</ion-content>
```

css

```
ion-content{
   --ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to top right, #2d4caf 0, #ce38a1 100%);
   opacity: 100%;
 }

 ion-input{
  background: none;
  opacity: 1;
 }


h2{
   color: black;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center !important;
   margin-top: 20%;
   margin-bottom: 15%;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

set background-color: transparent on the input.